# How to get asp:Table cell values using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

In my aspx file, I define an **asp:table** like below. I want to get its cell contents using Javascript. How can I do that?

*test.aspx*

```
<asp:Table ID="tableID" runat="server">
<asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableCell>
        <asp:Label runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>

<asp:TableRow>
    <asp:TableCell>
        <asp:Label runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </asp:TableCell>
    <asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </asp:TableCell>
</asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```

*Javascript part in test.aspx*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetCellContents() {
var table = document.getElementById('<%=tableID.ClientID %>');

//HERE I WANT TO GET CELL CONTENTS AS ARRAY OF STRING
}
</script>
```

Comment: `var contents = [].slice.call(table.getElementsByTagName("td")).map(function (el) { return el.textContent; });` - http://jsfiddle.net/47C53/

Comment: Thanks Ian, but it's not working :(

Comment: @Ian why not just `[].map.call(table.getElementsByTagName("td"), function (el) { return el.textContent; });` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/47C53/1/)) rather than slice->map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it like this:

```
var table = document.getElementById('<%=tableID.ClientID %>');
for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
    //get first column (labels)
    var lblCtrl = table.rows[i].cells[0].childNodes[0];
    //get second column (textBoxes)
    var txtCtrl = table.rows[i].cells[1].childNodes[0];
    //check that the second column is a textBox
    if (txtCtrl.tagName == "INPUT" || txtCtrl.tagName == "SELECT") {
        alert(txtCtrl.value);
    }
    if (!(lblCtrl.tagName == "INPUT" || lblCtrl.tagName == "SELECT"))
    {
        alert(lblCtrl.innerHTML);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `cssclass` to your cells and then you can use the `getElementsByClassName` Javascript function to get the elements.

Comment: Thanks, It's correct but adding a cssclass is not a good idea when each cell has a specific cssclass

Comment: Then you can add a cssclass to their parents and find the td elements inside the elements having the class. Also, you can have multiple classes for a tag, finally, in your code I did not see cssclass values.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your solution is working. There is another solution for this question and I attached it as answer.